# How to remove error 'ReferenceError: 'Symbol' is undefined' when using Mobx with react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm creating a test project to try Mobx with react. 
This is the procedure I followed

```
npm -i --save mobx mobx-react
npm run eject
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

Set "experimentalDecorators": true in tsconfig.json

Added the plugins part to package.json file inside babel:

```
{
"plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

This is my code:

**Root.tsx**

```js
import {Provider} from 'mobx-react';
import * as React from 'react';
import AssetsStore from '../Store/AssetsStore';
import AddAsset from './AddAsset';
import DisplayAssets from'./DisplayAssets';

const assetsStore = new AssetsStore();

class Root extends React.Component{

    public render(){
        return(
            <Provider assetStore = {assetsStore}>
                <AddAsset/>
                <DisplayAssets/>
            </Provider>
        )
    }

}

export default Root;
```

**AddAsset.tsx**

```js
import { inject } from 'mobx-react';
import* as React from 'react';
import AssetsStore from '../Store/AssetsStore';

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
interface IProps{    
}

interface IAsset{
    assetname:string
}

// try removiing IProps from here
interface InjectedProps extends IProps{
    assetsStore:AssetsStore
}

@inject('assetsStore')
export default class AddAsset extends React.Component<IProps,IAsset>{
    public assetStore:AssetsStore;
    constructor(props:IProps){
        super(props);

        this.state ={
            assetname : ''
        }
        this.assetStore = this.injected.assetsStore
    }    

    public onAssetChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>{
        this.setState({
            assetname:event.target.value
        })
        if(event.target.accessKey === '13' && this.state.assetname!==''){
            this.assetStore.addAsset(this.state.assetname);
        }        
    }

    get injected(){
        return this.props as InjectedProps;
    }

    public render(){
        return(
            <input value={this.state.assetname} onChange={this.onAssetChange}/>
        )
    }
}
```

**DisplayAssets.tsx**

```js
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react';
import * as React from 'react';
import AssetsStore from '../Store/AssetsStore';

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
interface IProps{    
}

interface InjectedProps extends IProps{
    assetsStore:AssetsStore
}
@inject('assetsStore')
@observer
class DisplayAssets extends React.Component<IProps>{
    public assetsStore:AssetsStore;
    
    constructor(props:IProps){
        super(props);

        this.assetsStore = this.injected.assetsStore;
    }

    get injected(){
        return this.props as InjectedProps;
    }

    public render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {
                    Object.keys(this.assetsStore.assets).map((asset, index) =>{
                        return <li key={index}>{asset}</li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default DisplayAssets;
```

***The code is compiling successfully. But I'm getting error a runtime error on the browser. I've attached an image which displays the error***.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDhnB.png)

Even I tried adding a new package:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
```

And changed the plugin to

```
"plugins": [
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators"
]
```

But getting same error
What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Symbol is a JSCore feature which is apparently still missing in your project.

A simple fix is downgrading to mobx version 4.X

see https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1889